# Elixir - scrub_params

Tags: elixir

I'm new to Phoenix.  Working through some sample code.  When I add this line to my controller, I still get empty strings sent through:

```
defmodule Rumbl.VideoController do
  use Rumbl.Web, :controller

  plug :scrub_params, "video" when action in [:create, :update]

  ...

end
```

The output on the console is the same with and without the scrub line:

```
    [debug] Processing by Rumbl.VideoController.create/2
  Parameters: %{"_csrf_token" => "CCUkZDU1fE8nTy1tNRcHJVBYBkNPEAAApcT1sfHwwvd9bn3H85Ul7w==", "_utf8" => "Γ£ô", "video" => %{"description" => "", "title" => "", "url" => ""}}
  Pipelines: [:browser, :authenticate_user]
```

Any thoughts out there?

Comment: You added the `scrub_params` plug to your `VideoController`. But the line you showed in the console is for the `UserController`. Did you try adding this to the same controller?

Comment: IO.inspect the "video" in your method. I guess the console shows you the param before to be "scrubed".

Answer (score 0):

> plug :scrub_params, "video" when action in [:create, :update]
>
> HTML forms don’t have the concept of nil so every time blank input is sent through the form, it will arrive as an empty string to our Phoenix application. If we left our application that way, those empty strings would leak throughout our whole application, forcing us to differentiate between nil and blank strings everywhere.
>
> Instead, we can use the scrub_params function, letting us deal with that problem right at the boundary. Dealing with user input is exactly what we want our controller to do. scrub_params will check and transform any empty string into nil for any data inside the “video” parameter, allowing us to treat our data in a much more uniform way.

This is from **Programming Phoenix, Chapter 6. Ecto Queries and Generators** (ISBN-13: 978-1-68050-145-2) at page 100.

This means, that `scrub_params` moves the empty strings of the arriving video attributes to nil only. Your log output demonstrates that you receive empty string attributes in your controller action before they will be moved to nil via scrub_params.

You should check why your source (html form or something else) sends empty attributes.